# DictionaryBase to generics . 

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

if i have a .net 1.1 class that inherits from DictionaryBase  and i am moving this to 2.0.. what is the generics equivalent to change this to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx)

Comment: KeyedCollection has the keys embedded in the values, which is not equivalent to DictionaryBase. Note that you can inherit from Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, but it doesn't have the virtual hooks you may need to customize its behaviour.